# Unchecking a checkbox, and clearing out a dropdown menu on a form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am wondering how to clear a checkbox and dropdown menu on submit. I have other fields such as name, email and password that clear out using this code:

```js
 const formSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("form submitted!")
        setFormState({name:"", email: "", password: "", role:"", terms: ""})
```

But it does not clear out both role (which is the drop down) and terms (which is the checkbox). I am unsure how to get them to go back to default once submit is hit.

Edit: So here is my code for both the roles and terms section:

```js
<Label htmlFor="roles">
      What is your role?
        <Select
            value={formState.roles}
            name="role"
            id="roles"
            onChange={inputChange}
             >
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled" value="Select 
                One">Select One</option>
            <option value="Full Stack Web Developer">Full Stack Web 
                 Developer</option>
            <option value="Android Developer">Android 
                 Developer</option>
            <option value="iOS Developer">iOS Developer</option>
            <option value="UX/UI Designer">UX/UI Designer</option>
          </Select>
           {errorState.role.length > 0 ? (<Paragraph>{errorState.role}. 
             </Paragraph>) : null}
        </Label>
        <Label htmlFor="terms">
            Terms & Conditions
            <CheckboxInput
                type="checkbox"
                name="terms"
                id="terms"
                value={formState.terms}
                onChange={inputChange}
            />
            {errorState.terms.length > 0 ? (<Paragraph>{errorState.terms}. 
           </Paragraph>) : null}
        </Label>
```

If anymore information is needed just let me know!

Comment: Can you share the code of the checkbox and drop down?

Comment: Yes, I will add to my main question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `CheckboxInput`'s `value` prop to `checked`. This also means that both your `inputChange` handler needs to be altered a bit to handle checkbox types and your `terms` state should store `boolean` instead of `string`.

```js
<CheckboxInput
  type="checkbox"
  name="terms"
  id="terms"
  checked={formState.terms}
  onChange={inputChange}
/>
```

```js
setFormState({ name:"", email: "", password: "", role:"", terms: false })
```

Now the `Select`'s default option seems to have two values.

```js
<option value="" disabled={true} value="Select One">Select One</option>
```

You can keep the first one `value=""` in order to work.

```js
<option value="" disabled={true}>Select One</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

For your `checkbox`, maintain a boolean state for  and use a separate onChange by making use of `checked` (not value)

Working [demo is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/drop-down-clear-on-submit-issue-fix-r9pjt?file=/src/App.js)

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
export default function App() {
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
    role: "",
    terms: false
  });

  const formSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("form submitted!");
    setFormState({ name: "", email: "", password: "", role: "", terms: false });
  };
  const inputChange = e => {
    const target = e.target;
    console.log(target.value);
    setFormState(prev => ({ ...prev, [target.name]: target.value }));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <form onSubmit={formSubmit}>
        <select
          value={formState.role}
          name="role"
          id="roles"
          onChange={inputChange}
        >
          <option
            selected={true}
            // disabled="disabled"
            value="select 
                One"
          >
            Select One
          </option>
          <option value="Full Stack Web Developer">
            Full Stack Web Developer
          </option>
          <option value="Android Developer">Android Developer</option>
          <option value="iOS Developer">iOS Developer</option>
          <option value="UX/UI Designer">UX/UI Designer</option>
        </select>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="terms"
          id="terms"
          value={formState.terms}
          checked={formState.terms}
          onChange={e => {
            const target = e.target;
            setFormState(prev => ({ ...prev, terms: target.checked }));
          }}
        />
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In formSubmit event can you try to set dropdown value as default value as below:

```
setFormState({name:"", email: "", password: "", role:"Select One", terms: ""})
```

For Checking-Unchecking checkbox in React, you can refer below link for detailed explanation.
[uncheck checkbox programmatically in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43602665/uncheck-checkbox-programmatically-in-reactjs)

Answer (score -1):

It is normal. If I understand your code well, firstly for the roles, in the setState your are setting for "role" whereas in your form you are using "form.roles". And secondly for checkbox use checked property instead and it is boolean and not string.